# Email Live Checking PHP and Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I have an issue im stuck for 3 days. Im trying to check in DB if the email the user is entering is already registered and avoid registering in duplicate. But this doesn't seem to work fine

here is my code:

This is in the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cf_email").keyup(function(e) {
       var uname = $(this).val();
       if (uname == "")
       {
           $("#msg").html("");
           $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
       }
       else
       {
           $("#msg").html("Verificando, espere...");
           $.ajax({
               url: "check_availability.php",
               data: {Email: uname},
               type: "POST",
               success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == true) {
                    $("#msg").html('<span class="text-danger">Email ya registrado!</span>');
                    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $("#msg").html('<span class="text-success">Email Disponible para Registrar!</span>');
                    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
   });
  });
</script>

<right><form id="register" action="contact.php" method="post">
      <p><label>E-mail para Registro</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="cf_email" id="cf_email" title="Email"  class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Email Valido" required><div id="msg" class="form-group"></div>
</form></right>
```

this is the check_availability.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST["cf_email"]) && $_POST['cf_email'] != '')
{

   $response = array();
   $cfmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cf_email']);
   $sql  = "select Email from Bares where Email='".$cfmail."'";
   $res    = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   $count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
   if($count > 0)
   {
     $response['status'] = false;
     $response['msg'] = 'email already exists.';
   }
   else
   {
     $response['status'] = true;
     $response['msg'] = 'email is available.';
   }
   echo json_encode($response);

  }
?>
```

it doesn't matter which email i introduce in the textfield because always says its available even if the email is registered already in the database

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: echo the query and run it manually agains the db. What's the result? (@tadman this question is not about security. Suggestions are welcome but let's keep on topic.)

Comment: @T30 It's always about security. We live in an era where we cannot hand-wave this away. Even a tiny mistake by a junior developer can have [disastrous consequences](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/). If you do this stuff properly, by the book, then injection problems don't exist. As a bonus you never have to wrestle ugly escaping bugs, or waste time tracking down a missing apostrophe in your query.

Comment: im not so expert in PHP and HTML, I really dont know that much in this language, as I do in VB.NET or Cocoa or Swift I just dont find the way to solve it

Comment: @T30 i have done an echo but nothing happened, nothing shown

Comment: No sorry @tadman, the security is a matter of context. You could blame almost _any_ question with security issues. But if the meaning of this website is to help people quickly, we should use the minimum amount of code in our examples, without bothering about issues that are totally unrelated to the issue. As well we should do in the comments.

Comment: SQL injection bugs are rampant in the PHP community and yet not in others like Perl, Python, Ruby or Node.js because those other communities are quick to point out any potential security problems and steer people towards best practices and away from hazardous habits. Maybe you haven't noticed, but this is something I flag on any and all questions with security problems, and after years of consistent flagging, I'm not the only one doing it, either. This is **important** to get right. This is **fundamental** to developing web applications.

Comment: I really admire your aim to redempt the php community, but this isn't the place and the way for doing it.
Writing two full comments just for pointing out a thing totally unrelated to the topic is dangerously near the troll behaviour.
This is a Q&A site, its aim is to help people with specific questions. We try to keep it clean closing questions that are too broad, we shouldn't make the same mistake in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you're processing a string, not an object. You need to parse it:

```
success: function(data) {
    dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    if(dataObj.status == true) {
         ....
```

Comment: Adding `dataType: "json"` should do this for you automatically. There's no need to manually parse.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Example with mysqli OOP try it will work without Problem:
PHP:

```
<?php $mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'utf8');

if (!empty($_POST['cf_email'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $sql=$mysqli->query("select Email from Bares where Email='".$cf_email."'");
    if($sql->num_row>0){
        $status=1;
    }
    else{
        $status=0;
    }
    echo $status;
die;}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<right>
  <form id="register" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p><label>E-mail para Registro</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="cf_email" id="cf_email" title="Email" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Email Valido" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <div id="msg" class="form-group"></div>
  </form>
</right>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_email").keyup(function(e) {
    var uname = $(this).val();
    if (uname == "") {
      $("#msg").html("");
      $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 1) {
            $("#msg").html('<span class="text-danger">Email ya registrado!</span>');
            $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);
          } else {
            $("#msg").html('<span class="text-success">Email Disponible para Registrar!</span>');
            $("#submit").attr('disabled', false);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: still the same issue, stuck in  $("#msg").html("Verificando, espere...");

Comment: Have you used my code or edited it to you code, and can I see the new code how you use it?

Comment: oooh now I see the Problem I have updated the php code, $staus

Comment: stuck in the same part

Comment: Okay, can I see the new Code?

Comment: can I see the new it?

Comment: `code`php $mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'utf8');

if (!empty($_POST['cf_email'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $sql=$mysqli->query("select Email from Bares where Email='".$cf_email."'");
    if($sql->num_row>0){
        $status=1;
    }
    else{
        $status=0;
    }
    echo $status;
die;}`code`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157600/discussion-between-manuel-perez-and-ferhad-othman).